# Unsure what I'm doing wrong when trying to create / add this command:

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

XAML Button:

```
<Button Content="Test Connection" Name="btnTestConnection" Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=someObject}"/>
```

View Model:

```
public ICommand TestCommand
{
    get;
    internal set;
}

private bool CanExecuteTestCommand()
{
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtControl);
}

private void CreateTestCommand()
{
    TestCommand = new TestCommand(TestExecute);
}

public void TestExecute(object parameter)
{
    //do stuff with parameter

    obj.TestConnection(parameter);
}
```

I would like to point out that `CreateTestCommand()` is called in my VM constructor.

And finally, my implementation of `TestCommand`:

```
class TestCommand : ICommand
{
   private Action<object> execute;

   private Predicate<object> canExecute;

   private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;

   public TestCommand(Action<object> execute)
       : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute)
   {
   }

   public TestCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
   {
       if (execute == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
       }

       if (canExecute == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("canExecute");
       }

       this.execute = execute;
       this.canExecute = canExecute;
   }

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
   {
       add
       {
           CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
           this.CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
       }

       remove
       {
           CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
           this.CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
       }
   }

   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
   {
       return this.canExecute != null && this.canExecute(parameter);
   }

   public void Execute(object parameter)
   {
       this.execute(parameter);
   }

   public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
   {
       EventHandler handler = this.CanExecuteChangedInternal;
       if (handler != null)
       {
           handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
       }
   }

   public void Destroy()
   {
       this.canExecute = _ => false;
       this.execute = _ => { return; };
   }

   private static bool DefaultCanExecute(object parameter)
   {
       return true;
   }
}
```

I set a breakpoint in `CreateTestCommand` and it looks like it's configured properly:

[image]

But when I click on `btnTestConnection`, nothing happens. `TestExecute` in my View Model isn't called (which calls `TestConnection` on the actual model). I must be missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure out what...

**EDIT** Including the rest of my view model;

```
class FormProcessorViewModel
{
    FormProcessorModel obj;

    public FormProcessorViewModel()
    {
        obj = new FormProcessorModel();
        CreateTestCommand();
    }

    public FormProcessorViewModel(string server, string database, string username, bool specifyDateRange, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string operation, string preprocessed, string processed, string failed) :this()
    {
        txtServer = server;
        txtDatabase = database;
        txtUsername = username;
        chkSpecifyDateRange = specifyDateRange;
        dpStartDate = startDate;
        dpEndDate = endDate;
        txtOperation = operation;
        txtPreprocessed = preprocessed;
        txtProcessed = processed;
        txtFailed = failed;
    }

    public ICommand TestCmd
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteTestCommand()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername);
    }

    private void CreateTestCommand()
    {
        TestCmd = new TestCommand(TestExecute);
    }

    private void TestExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var passwordBox = parameter as PasswordBox;
        var password = passwordBox.Password;

        obj.TestConnection(password);
    }

}
```

I left out all the properties that get set in the second constructor just because they don't really do anything but refer to the corresponding values on the model object.

Comment: I think it might help to see the VM, so we can have a look at the binding and datacontext.

Comment: Does the output window show any binding errors?

Comment: @PScr Edited and added the rest of the VM

Comment: @StillLearnin No, output doesn't show anything whatsoever.

Comment: You bind `Command` in the XAML to a `public ICommand` property, but here your `ICommand` property name does not match the XAML binding, and you should probably have the method named different than the `ICommand` property too.

Comment: @crashmstr Ah-ha, that's it. Thank you! I renamed it after Sandesh's answer but I forgot to rename it in the XAML, too.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

View Model

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private string _test;

    public string TestValue
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TestValue"); }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; internal set; }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        TestValue = "Test";
        CreateTestCommand();
    }

    private void CreateTestCommand()
    {
        MyCommand = new TestCommand(ExecuteButton);
    }

    private void ExecuteButton(object obj)
    {
        TestValue = "Cool";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
        {
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Button Content="{Binding TestValue}" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Xaml Code behind.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Renaming `TestCommand` to `TestCmd` did not change the behavior at all; the `TestExecute` in the VM doesn't trigger and nor does the actual method in the model.

Comment: Let me give the entire snippet which I used.

Comment: Button text is blank when I click it, using your code with the property changed implementation.

Comment: It works perfectly at my end. Not sure why the button text goes blank at your end